Microsoft Teams auto starts and opens on login despite disabling this setting
I don't use Microsoft Teams very often. I only use it occasionally, so I don't want it to auto-start when I open my PC. I have two accounts: A personal account and a university account. On both accounts, I disabled the auto-start option:

and yet, every time I open my computer, I am granted with Microsoft Teams opening. It just pops up and I can't figure out how to stop it from auto-starting. I'd prefer to do that in the app instead of disabling it in the task manager if it's possible. Why doesn't Microsoft Teams respect the Auto-start Teams option being unchecked and how can I stop it from auto-starting?

Are you 100% sure there's not a shortcut in shell:startup for teams, or another way to auto-start teams? If the pc is domain joined, it could be setup in a logon script too for example.

It's my personal desktop PC and as far as I am aware, there is no shortcut to startup teams or anything like that.

Microsoft's Sysinternals makes a free app, Autoruns, that lists all code that runs on bootup, login, as a service, as a scheduled task, etc.
Run Autoruns, and search for Teams. There may be more than one place where it's started. Also, run that check as Administrator and as a regular user -- auto startup might might have been set in both profiles on installation.
Autoruns can directly disable startup, or you can try making the change yourself (e.g., removing Teams from C:\Users\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp, as well as from your own StartUp folder

I ran it and found a registry entry Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run for TeamsMachineInstaller. I suspect it's the culprit. How can I disable this? I'd rather do it from Team's interface instead of messing with the registry.

As stated in the answer, use Microsoft's own tool, Autoruns, to disable that entry (allowing it to be re-enabled later), or to delete that entry.

Ok. It's just weird to me that the auto-start option is disabled in Teams and it still starts every time I turn on my computer.
